# How do I make a target in a makefile invoke another target in the makefile

Tags: c++, unix, ubuntu, makefile

So I have this makefile and I want the target all just  to invoke the target expertest, but apparently the way I'm doing it is wrong because i'm getting the error 
"make: exprtest: Command not found
make: *** [all] Error 127
"
this is the makefile:

```
all:
    exprtest
exprtest: exptrtest.o driver.o parser.tab.o scanner.o
    g++ -Wall -g -o exprtest exptrtest.o driver.o parser.tab.o scanner.o
driver.o: driver.cpp scanner.hpp driver.hpp
    g++ -Wall -g -c driver.cpp
parser.tab.o: parser.tab.hpp parser.tab.cpp
    bison parser.ypp
    g++ -Wall -g -c parser.tab.cpp
scanner.o: scanner.cpp scanner.hpp
    flex -t scanner.ll > scanner.cpp
    g++ -Wall -g -c scanner.cpp
clean:
    rm parser.tab.hpp parser.tab.cpp scanner.cpp
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put `exprtest` on the same line as `all`.  Dependencies come after the colon, commands come on the following lines, indented.

```
target: dependencies
[tab] system command
```

So in your case it all becomes:

```
all: exprtest
exprtest: exptrtest.o driver.o parser.tab.o scanner.o
    g++ -Wall -g -o exprtest exptrtest.o driver.o parser.tab.o scanner.o
```

Answer (score 15):

And you can always have `make` call a new instance of `make`.
For example:

```
all:
    $(MAKE) exprtest

exprtest:  
    do exprtest stuff
```

Typing `make all` will indirectly do `make exprtest`.

Answer (score 6):

You want to do something like

```
all: exprtest
```

What that says is "`all` depends on `exprtest` to be successful".